# URLs in hover text break links

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, tooltips, markdown-rendering

A piece of markdown like this:

```
I was trying to do something with [this website][1], but it didn't work. How do I fix it?

  [1]: //example.com "Home - http://example.com, this website's tagline."
```

produces this:

> I was trying to do something with http://example.com, this website's tagline">this website, but it didn't work. How do I fix it?

As you can see, the HTML tag is closed just before the url string.

This is probably caused by the automatic link identifier being invoked everywhere, instead of just in the main post body. It's not invoked in places such as blockquotes (see above), inline code (e.g. `http://example.com`) or the URL part of a link (i.e. [this](//example.com) doesn't link to `<a>http://example.com</a>`), so this seems like it could be fixed without rewriting the whole codebase.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't think it's a duplicate. It's for the same reasons, yes, but it's a different question and I think this use-case will bring more attention to the issue.

Comment: Not sure. Jeff's last sentence (*Since the plain text alt for the image won't be clickable anyway, the http:// is irrelevant*) is fully relevant in your case as well.

Comment: @ShadowWizard But people could be copy-pasting / re-typing from a website's title in an attempt to make the post clearer, and it would subsequently not work. Might be enough to stop them posting it, if they noticed. If they didn't, it would be a glitchy-looking post without links.

Comment: Well, I still think it's close enough to be a dupe. I cast a single vote, only if four others will agree this will  get closed. And in case a dev will fix that, they can easily reopen even if it will get closed. (And retag the other question as well)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I fully understand that (although I didn't on my first, second or `n<8`th question), and was just posting a counter-argument for potential close-voters to muse on.